# Google analytcis problem with number of clicks and sessions

Tags: google-analytics, ads

I have some problem with google analytics. In the Google Ads campaign report, the number of clicks is six times higher than the number of sessions. I have no idea why.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/apIA5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Usually a discrepancy is physiological, however that indicated in the image is actually a bit high.
It could depend, for example, on the slow loading of pages or on the loss of the *gclic* parameter (for example in the case of redirects) or on an error on the site that blocks tracking.